# Google Custom Search Pagination Issue

Tags: search, google-custom-search

I have setup google custom search for my site but the resulted pagination it is showing is wrong or buggy. it shows 4 pages in the pagination but when i click on 3rd page the 4th link is gone. Is this a known issue with Google CSE. Has it got any solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue too and laughed when I found out this was a "feature" instead of a bug:

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/customsearch/troubleshooting-and-bugs/PngSBJW1Huk

Anyway, this should fix it.

Comment: Yeah except it isn't really a fix, it's still just a bug. You either have to show duplicate results or have broken paging. It isn't even clear if you can still do this with the new code for the search and they still have this bug.